# How do program types such as natural numbers figure into the Curry-Howard Isomorphism?

Tags: type-checking, coq, curry-howard

In Coq, the `nat`, the type of natural numbers, has type `Set`. By the Curry-Howard Isomorphism, all propositions of type `Prop` are types of corresponding proof terms. How do `nat`s or other instances of `Set` figure into this isomorphism?

In other words, is there a correspondent for `Set`s in the Curry-Howard isomorphism, as there is for `Prop`s and proof terms, or are they outside the things that have correspondents in the Curry-Howard Isomorphism?

Sorry for the imprecise wording, I'm struggling to express my question clearly, probably because of a poor understanding of the Curry-Howard Isomorphism, happy to be corrected on any misunderstandings I have expressed above.

Comment: I'm not certain if this is exactly what you're after, but... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding